AWS Config Custom Rule to detect IAM MFA is not being triggered
I'm creating a custom Lambda AWS Config rule to detect when a user does not have MFA activated.
I'm setting up the rule trigger type to happen when configuration changes, within the scope of the "AWS IAM User" resource.
But, unfortunattly, deleting or adding a MFA device to a IAM User does not trigger the rule. I can't understand why.
Making other types of changes, like changing the user permissions does trigger the rule. But, the changes of MFA Devices doesn't seem to work.
What is the best way to handle this situation?
I tried using Periodic rules instead, but they don't have the scope of "IAM User", which loses the point.
